# A problem on Closed Graph Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, closed-graph

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces. Let $\{f_i \} \subset Y^∗$ separates points in $Y$ . Suppose that $f_i T$ is continuous for each $f_i$ , then prove that $T$ is continuous.

I know that if I show that if $T: X \to Y$ is a closed map then the problem is solved. So, I need to show that Graph($T$) is closed i.e. for a sequence $\{x_n\}\in X$, if $x_n\to x$ and $T(x_n)\to y$ then $T(x)=y$.

But I am not sure how to use the concept of Dual of $Y$ to solve the problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The dual of $Y$ is actually totally irrelevant here.  We just have some collection of functionals $f_i$ on $Y$ with the properties described in the problem.  The mention of $Y^*$ is just notation to say that each $f_i$ is a functional on $Y$.

Comment: Okay, so from here we can deduce that $f_i(Tx_n)=f_i(y)=f_i(Tx)$ because $f_i T$ is continuous for all $f_i$.

Comment: And since $f_i$ separates points in $Y$, $Tx = y$, right?

Comment: Yep!  You can go ahead and write that up to answer your own question :)

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: $f_i(Tx_n) = f_i(y)$ is incorrect.

Comment: @EricWofsey Of course $Y^*$ matters here. $f_i\in Y^*$ means that $f_i$ is a *continuous linear* functional, which is important here.

Comment: If $f_i$ is a continuous linear functional on $Y$ then why $f_i(Tx_n)\neq f_i(y)$?

Answer (score 2):

Assume $x_n \to x$ and $Tx_n \to y$.

Since $f_i$ is continuous and $Tx_n \to y$, we have $f_i(Tx_n) \to f_i(y)$.

Since $f_i T$ is continuous and $x_n \to x$, we have $f_i(Tx_n) \to f_i(Tx)$.

Therefore $f_i(Tx) = f_i(y), \forall i$. Since $\{f_i\}$ separates points, we conclude $y = Tx$.